# summarise attributes from sf::st_intersection() where geometries overlaps

Tags: r, summarization, r-sf

I'd like to summarise attributes for a set of geometries, summing values where they overlaps.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("r-spatial/sf")
library(sf)
m = rbind(c(0,0), c(1,0), c(1,1), c(0,1), c(0,0))
p = st_polygon(list(m))
n = rbind(c(0.5,0.5), c(1.5,0.5), c(1.5,1.5), c(0.5,1.5), c(0.5,0.5))
q = st_polygon(list(n))
s = st_sfc(list(p, q))
sf = st_sf(s, att=c(1,1))
d = st_intersection(sf)
d$id <- 1:nrow(d)

plot(d['att'])
plot(st_centroid(d['att']), add = TRUE, col = 'red')
```

[image]

```
> d
#Simple feature collection with 3 features and 4 fields
#geometry type:  POLYGON
#dimension:      XY
#bbox:           xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 1.5 ymax: 1.5
#epsg (SRID):    NA
#proj4string:    NA
#  att                       geometry n.overlaps origins id
#1   1 POLYGON ((1 0.5, 1 0, 0 0, ...          1       1  1
#2   1 POLYGON ((0.5 1, 1 1, 1 0.5...          2    1, 2  2
#3   1 POLYGON ((0.5 1, 0.5 1.5, 1...          1       2  3
```

In the minimal example provided above I'd like to sum d$att and get att=2 for geometry #2 (the one corresponding to the overlap).

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `origins` list column to retrieve the polygons which "originated" the intersect, and then sum over their `att` column. Something like this could work (at least in this very simple use case...):

```
for (int in seq_along(d$id)) {
     d$att[int] = sum(sf[d$origins[[int]], ]$att, na.rm = TRUE)
}
> d
Simple feature collection with 3 features and 4 fields
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 1.5 ymax: 1.5
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
  att                       geometry n.overlaps origins id
1   1 POLYGON ((1 0.5, 1 0, 0 0, ...          1       1  1
2   2 POLYGON ((0.5 1, 1 1, 1 0.5...          2    1, 2  2
3   1 POLYGON ((0.5 1, 0.5 1.5, 1...          1       2  3
```

Comment: @Ibusett it seems to be working quite well. I just wonder how one would avoid a loop but I'll take it! Thanks!.

Comment: For sure it can be done with *apply/purrr, although sometimes I wonder why bothering with that  (unless there are performances issues), when the for-loop syntax is so much easier to read and understand (at least for me...)  ;-)